Android - Is it possible to modify the ACTION_SEND Intent?
Is it possible to modify/customize the Intent.ACTION_SEND? As of now I have:
 val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
 intent.type = MediaUtil.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE
 intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, title)
 intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message)
 return Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share with …")

which as expected shows the title and the message but no icon. I wonder if it is possible to modify it like add app icon, add hyperlinks etc.
For the Icon part I did most of the things I could find on the internet such as modifying the manifest file and adding filters to the activity followed this example, but nothing the icon is either the static one or none existent.
The hyperlinks part is a bit tricky. I want to use type = MediaUtil.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE not text/html. Tried by modifying the string to html format like so:
<string name="somelink"><![CDATA[<a href="https://google.com/">Google</a>]]></string>

but that did not work. Most of the apps I tried to send it to such as Slack are treating it as plain text not a hyper link.

ACTION_SEND is a protocol. How other apps interpret what you put into your ACTION_SEND Intent is up to the developers of those apps, not you. The behavior of those apps may change over time, may vary by hardware (e.g., OS level), and so on.
